# how to get forwarded page url in jsf

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, forward

```
@Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/hello")
                .setViewName("forward:/hi.xhtml");
    }
```

I use this code to forward my primefaces page
and I need to get the forwareded page url in my Bean class
I mean I need to get the    `"/hello"`
but this code :

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
```

give me the      `"/hi.xhtml"`
how can I get      `"/hello"`     ?

Comment: Why do you need this? Sounds like a bad design if your bean needs to know the name of your ui page

Comment: I want to use activiti engine ! I need one bean and 1 url to know which process need to be start and my bean automaticly redirect to other page by activiti engine ... I can make many bean that each do something but i dont want to make it hard code ,,, now i do it with sending id with url ... hi.xhtml?id=hello , I though other one would be better

Comment: You can use filter for it.